# invoice2.sty not found by LaTeX or LyX

Tags: lyx, texlive

I've looked at similar questions without seeing an answer to my situation.

Running TeXLive-20170520 and LyX-2.2.3 on Slackware-14.2.

From CTAN I downloaded the invoice2 package and built it. The files are in ~/documents/LaTeX/invoice2/. A copy was placed in /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/invoice2/ and texhash was run.

Neither lyx or latex can find invoice2.sty when it's included in the preamble (\usepackage{invoice2}). I cannot find it using kpsewhere (or kpsewhich). What step did I miss?

Comment: `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/invoice2/` seems to be the wrong place. Where is TeX Live 2017 located? Is there a `texmf-local` folder somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I figured out that the proper location is /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/invoice2. I removed all traces of TeX on my system and re-installed TeXLive-2017.171108 with extras and fonts. The invoice2.sty is part of that installation.

Comment: So your question is answered, I presume?

Answer (score 1):

The proper location is /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/invoice2/.

Comment: Don't use the distribution tree `/usr/share/texmf-dist` for non-distribution packages. Ask the TeX distribution for the correct tree, either `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` (local TEXMF tree for all users) or `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` (user local TEXMF tree).